# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction

Tags: typescript, next.js

I just started out with next.js and typescript and I'm gettin a typescript error in vscode. Although it does not affect the outcome of my state variable, I'd like to know why the error occurs and how to deal with it

My error msg: "*Argument of type 'Movie | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Movie | null>'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Movie | null>'*"

Tsx snippet:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Movie } from "typings";

interface Props {
  netflixOriginals: Movie[];
}

export default function Banner({ netflixOriginals }: Props) {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMovie(
      netflixOriginals[Math.floor(Math.random() * netflixOriginals.length)]
    );
  }, [netflixOriginals]);

  console.log(movie);
```

This line gives error when setting state:
`netflixOriginals[Math.floor(Math.random() * netflixOriginals.length)]`

typings file:

```
  export interface Movie {
    title: string
    backdrop_path: string
    media_type?: string
    release_date?: string
    first_air_date: string
    genre_ids: number[]
    id: number
    name: string
    origin_country: string[]
    original_language: string
    original_name: string
    overview: string
    popularity: number
    poster_path: string
    vote_average: number
    vote_count: number
  }
```

Console logging the state gives back random item from the list. I would just like to know how to write that bit correctly according to type script rules.

I see if the array would be empty, then it would get back an 'undefined' value, but I can make sure that it always has some elements in it from parent component. But how to tell typescript that it will always return a 'Movie' type

Comment: `netflixOriginals` could be undefined or an empty array in your code...

Comment: is undefined assignable to null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pick an element from a list of `Movie` like this: `netflixOriginals[some_random_number]` the type of that expression is `Movie|undefined`.

You defined your state as `Movie|null` you can try to change `null` into `undefined`.

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie | null>(null);
```

Becomes

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie | undefined>(undefined);
```

Comment: This also works, and is simpler, and in my use case, might be better as well. Thanks!

Comment: You can also omit the `undefined` and it'll still work. `useState<Movie>()`